# BeforeDoubleClick code placing data based on where cursor currently exists

Tags: vba, excel, insert-update, boolean-expression, database-cursor

I may or may not have an easy one here... For some reason I can't properly think of the solution.

Spreadsheet has numbers 1 to 14 in column A.  14 ends on row 15 as there is a header in cell A1.  What I'm trying to do is double click one of these numbers and transfer that number to a specific cell on the same sheet (named "Sheet1").  I was able to put the code together to make it work for transferring a chosen number to a specific cell.  Code below works well.  However, I don't want to add a bunch of areas to double click for different cells.  For example: The destination cell for the chosen data is E6, H6, and G6. I'd like to place the cursor starting in E6, double click a number in range A2 to A15, and have that number that I choose between A2 and A15 to appear in E6 since that is where the cursor was when I double clicked a cell in A2 to A15.  Then I would move the cursor by click H6 and then going back to same selection between A2 to A15, placing whatever number I choose in that range in H6 since that is where the cursor currently exists.

Hopefully this makes sense and is even possible.

#### example screenshot

[image: example screenshot]

Working code that allows the double click to put data in a certain cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A15")) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True
    Target.Copy Destination:=Cells(6, "E")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added the solution I would try, with comments in the code. The reason for **two** sheet variables, is because the first click in the double-click registers as a `SelectionChange` event. So to get the correct cell location, you need it from two selections back, instead of just one.

```
Public selectedCell As String 'Sheet Variable
Public lastCell As String

' This updates the Sheet variable with the most recent selection
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    selectedCell = lastCell
    lastCell = Target.Address
End Sub

' Added a check for having a previously selected cell
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A15")) Is Nothing Then
        If selectedCell = vbNullString Then
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "Please select a destination cell for the data."
            selectedCell = vbNullString
            lastCell = vbNullString 'Prevents overwriting same cell by accident
        Else
            Cancel = True
            Target.Copy Destination:=Range(selectedCell)
            selectedCell = vbNullString
            lastCell = vbNullString 'Prevents overwriting same cell by accident
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Extremely helpful on both answers.  Thank you.  However, one thing I'm struggling a bit with.  The data I was using as an example above was a set of data points I'm using on another spreadsheet that includes a slew of macros along with command buttons.  When I used your examples above on a separate spreadsheet with no macros it worked perfectly.  When I try to implement that same code into my other spreadsheet with the macros, the code doesn't work and the 'view code' section freezes.  My limited knowledge of vba is going to be apparent here, but I surely do appreciate everything.

Comment: @Dave Are any of the other macros in worksheet or workbook events? (Particularly, `SelectionChange` or `BeforeDoubleClick`?) Do any of the macros have `.Select` in them? (Particularly, referencing a cell or range such as `Range("A1").Select`?) Do any of them simulate double-clicking a cell on the sheet? Do any of the macros have `Application.EnableEvents = False`? If so, do they have the companion code `Application.EnableEvents = True`, as well, where it **will always run** before the code ends?

Comment: SelectionChange is in there for a Worksheet macro (Using it to center a button on sheet2 when I click the screen. Basically sheet2 has a lot of data transferred to it and the range of data can be large per cell going all the way to Column AB.  So when I enter sheet2 I could be under column T, and I don't want to scroll to find the button so the button centers to the section I'm on).  There is a macro that references .range("K8").select. No none simulate double-clicking a cell.  No Application.EnableEvents is not used anywhere else.

Comment: @Dave I also was assuming that you would not be moving data cross-sheets. If you are, that could be part of the issue as well.

Comment: @Dave Since you have other macros under the `SelectionChange` event, I'm assuming you combined your existing macros with the code from the `SelectionChange` in my answer?  Also, the macro that references `.Range("K8").Select`: Is the `.Select` necessary for the code? Or can you re-write it out?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny tool that you may be able to adapt to your needs.  If you double-click on an empty cell, it becomes the *FinalDestination*.  If you then double-click on another cell that is not empty, its contents will be copied to *FinalDestination*:

In the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Set FinalDestination = Target
        Else
            Target.Copy FinalDestination
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In a standard module:

```
Public FinalDestination As Range
```

**NOTE:**

In this simple demo code there are no restrictions on source/destination.